# Update query based on Select query giving "too many fields defined" error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table with about 40 fields, my select query contains 7 fields and I have an update query based on the results of the select query. This is all called by VBA from a button click on a form. Running the queries separately is no problem, but using the button returns "Too Many Fields Defined." I'm nowhere near the 255 field limit, and my table only has about 10,000 records. Compacting/Repairing didn't fix it, neither did making a new copy of the main table. I can't figure this out, can someone help me troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Please share the code you're using, and try to provide a [mcve]. Try to share the SQL both in the context of your VBA sub, and as an SQL statement (without the quotes).

Comment: SELECT [Fraud Data - Master].[Passenger Name], [Fraud Data - Master].Program, [Fraud Data - Master].[Account Number], [Fraud Data - Master].[Email Address], [Fraud Data - Master].CCList
FROM [Fraud Data - Master]
WHERE ((([Fraud Data - Master].CCList)=No) AND (([Fraud Data - Master].Status)=Fraud)) OR ((([Fraud Data - Master].CCList)=No) AND (([Fraud Data - Master].[Status From Cap1])=Confirmed Fraud));

Comment: `Dim myQuery As String
Dim myExportName As String
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook

myQuery = "CCListQuery"
myExportName = "X:\Boise Call Center\Departments\CXFraud\Macros-Scripts\CC\Blacklist Export.xlsm"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, myQuery, myExportName

Set xlApp = Excel.Application
 Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("X:\Boise Call Center\Departments\CXFraud\Macros-Scripts\CC\Blacklist Export.xlsm")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWorkbook = Nothing`

Comment: UPDATE CCListQuery INNER JOIN [Fraud Data - Master] ON (CCListQuery.CCList = [Fraud Data - Master].CCList) AND (CCListQuery.[Email Address] = [Fraud Data - Master].[Email Address]) AND (CCListQuery.[Account Number] = [Fraud Data - Master].[Account Number]) AND (CCListQuery.Program = [Fraud Data - Master].Program) AND (CCListQuery.[Passenger Name] = [Fraud Data - Master].[Passenger Name]) SET [Fraud Data - Master].CCList = Yes
WHERE (((CCListQuery.CCList)=No));

Answer (score 0):

So, I found that the issue arises from the selection of the "Show" property of the Select query my Update query references. If I select "Show," I get "Too Many Fields Defined" but if left unchecked, Access asks for the input from the field I'm not showing.

As I only want to update the records in the table that the select query found, I'm now at a loss as to work around this, besides creating separate queries and piecing the information together that way.

Any input, advice or anything would be appreciated.